# WPF, xaml grid with TabControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, tabcontrol

I have an application (implemenented in WPF, XAML) which has 6 rows and 6 columns. At the position `Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="5"` , I'm using a `TabControl` for ***Dashboard***, ***Housekeeping***, and ***Science***. In every `TabControl`, I'm using a `ListBox` on the left side to choose individual data. The rest (w/o the `ListBox`) of the field/grid (which should have a size of 4 rows and 4 columns) is available for charts.

**Problem**

The charts which are visible in the screenshot below should be stretched over 4 rows down to the bottom edge of the application according to the XAML code. The `TabControl` is not 4 rows as visible because of the white boarder I have attached.

How can I change my grid-concept that it works as described above? Is a grid in the grid, resp. in the `TabControl` necessary at all?

**Screenshot of the WPF application**

[image]

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>


<Grid>
    <!-- Definition of Rows and Columns -->
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="250" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Header -->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6">

        <TextBlock Text="RFM DATA ANALYZER" Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Thin"  />

    </StackPanel>


    <!-- Tabs -->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
        <TabControl  TabStripPlacement="Top">
            <TabItem Header="Dashboard">
                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Grid>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
                            <TextBlock Text="Data" Margin="0 50 0 20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="15" Foreground="LightGray" />
                            <ListBox >
                                <ListBoxItem Content="Data 00" />
                                <ListBoxItem Content="Data 01" />
                                <ListBoxItem Content="Data 03" />
                            </ListBox>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding Model1}" Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="1" />
                        <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding Model2}" Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="2"  Grid.ColumnSpan="1" />
                        <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding Model3}" Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="3"  Grid.ColumnSpan="1" />
                        <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding Model4}" Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="4"  Grid.ColumnSpan="1" />

                    </Grid>
                </Border>

            </TabItem>

            <TabItem Header="Housekeeping" Height="40">
                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `StackPanel`s with `Grid`s. `StackPanel`s size to their child elements, whereas `Grid`s size to their parent.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
        <TabControl  TabStripPlacement="Top">
```

...becomes...

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
        <TabControl  TabStripPlacement="Top">
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy :-) Thank you. But for all the other fields of the application I use StackPanel too. Is that wrong, even if it works?

Comment: Its a common mistake when learning XAML. When you need a control that fills the whole area of the parent, you most likely need a Grid, StackPanel is for when you want to align some controls next to each other. Get to know the best usage for each control.